# Spring RestTemplate JSON Response truncated

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing a REST Client that is required to make calls to retrieve records from a Virtualized Data Store using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE, meaning underlying Spring Framework is 5.2.2.RELEASE.

My issue is with the response processing as it comes from the server.  When I use the spring infrastructure to process the request and response the JSON body is stripped out.

Here is a snip of the latest code I have tried:

```
ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
RestTemplate rt = restTemplateBuilder
                  .basicAuthentication(username, password)
                  .build()
rt.setRequestFactory(factory)
String uriString = targetString
final String response = rt.getForObject(uriString,String.class)
 println("Response: ${response}")
```

This is supposed to return the JSON payload as string (just for testing purposes) looking something like this (important data has been redacted):

```
  "Salesforce_Truck_TripsResponse": {
    "Salesforce_Truck_TripsResult": {
      "row": [
        {
          "TICKET_NUMBER": "06805",
          "SCALE_TICKET_NUMBER": null,
          "PRODUCTION_DATE": "2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "TRUCK_UNIT_NUMBER": "60028",
          "TICKET_PRODUCT": "EMULSION",
          "TICKET_TYPE": "O",
          "INTERNAL_FLAG": "Y",
          "TRUCK_CONFIGURATION": "B3X",
          "FLUID_VOLUME": 6.0000000000,
          "BATTERY_LOCATION": "hidden",
          "BATTERY_NAME": "hidden",
          "TO_FROM_LOCATION": "hidden",
          "TO_FROM_NAME": "hidden",
          "EXT_LOC_NAME": null,
          "EXT_LOC": null,
          "FIELD_NAME": "hidden",
          "VENDOR_NAME": "Some Vendor"
        },
        {.....more of the same (many, many, more) },....
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Instead I am getting the following:

```
Response: {"Salesforce_Truck_TripsResponse":{"Salesforce_Truck_TripsResult":[]}}
```

When I use the following code:

```
String username = username
String password = password
String authString = "${username}:${password}"
byte[] authEnvBytes = Base64.encoder.encode(authString.getBytes())
String authStringEnc = new String(authEnvBytes)

URL url = new URL(targetString)
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic ${authStringEnc}")
conn.setRequestMethod("GET")
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json")

if(conn.getResponseCode() != 200){
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed!: HTTP error code: ${conn.getResponseCode()}")
}

String responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(conn.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset())
println responseBody
```

I get what I expected.

I have tried using different `ClientHttpRequestFactory` options to see if it is a buffering issue, no luck.

I have tried using every `MessageConverter` in the Spring library, no luck there either.

I have implemented an Interceptor on the RestTemplate to dump the request and response information as per:  https://objectpartners.com/2018/03/01/log-your-resttemplate-request-and-response-without-destroying-the-body/ blog post.

My response headers are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2020 20:48:59 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I am at the point where I am just going to drop my working code inside one of the calling methods and use that, but I wanted to see if I am missing some simple configuration issue in the Spring Framework.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i see Transfer-Encoding: chunked that means response is coming as chunked.

Comment: Yes, but when I dug into the spring source code it appears to handle that.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is something special in spring that I have to do to handle chunked data?